Apache Camel BigQuery Producer ignoring GCP Project ID
I am trying to use the apache camel gcp bigquery producer and noticed that it seems to be ignoring the project id entry.
I have the following:
.to(“google-bigquery:project-2:data_set-1:table_1”)

// along with the following in the properties file.
// camel.component.google-bigquery-sql.project-id=project-2

when i run this while "connected" to project-1 (via gcloud). i get an exception that
  project-1.data_set-1.table_1 does not exist

I've tried version 3.18 and 3.21 with the same result.
can anyone tell me what i am missing here?
thanks
